# What's the state of art steps to calculate the position of an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Suppose the event is `e`. How to know where it happened (as in position)?

I'm also using jQuery.

Comment: position as in mouse position?

Comment: by where you mean position or control that raised event?

Comment: Nothing to do with javascript is "State of the art"... it's all ugly as hell.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`e.pageX` and `e.pageY`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position):

```
$('#something').click(function(e) {
  alert('event happended at ' + e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[e.target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp) gives the object that triggered the event.